# Does Serializable isolation level protect databases against ACIDRain attack?

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql, serializable, transaction-isolation

[ACIDRain attack paper by Todd Warszawski, Peter Bailis.](http://www.bailis.org/papers/acidrain-sigmod2017.pdf)

[A high-level overview blogpost](https://www.bizety.com/2018/09/24/acidrain-concurrency-attacks-on-database-backed-applications/) on this paper.

Many applications were found to be vulnerable to this, eg. WooCommerce, Opencart.

There are two types of anomaly that ACIDRain attacks could trigger, dependent on the application involved:

1. Level-based isolation anomalies, which are races due to isolation
   settings at the database-level i.e. the database may not support
   serializability, or may not have been configured to do so (this is
   the case for most deployed databases in the wild).
2. Scoping isolation
   anomalies, which occur when an application programmer fails to
   correctly encapsulate logic using transactions. This enables
   concurrent requests to impact behavior that could not have arisen
   sequentially.

It sounds like both can be solved by enforcing Serializable isolation level for transactions. Is it correct?

Also, some database doesn't have real Serializable isolation level, for example Oracle. What can be done to protect them from this type of attack?

Comment: @APC Write skew is possible with Serializable isolation in Oracle. [Link](https://blog.dbi-services.com/oracle-serializable-is-not-serializable/)

Answer (score 4):

To use SERIALIZABLE to guarantee truly serial transactions, every transaction would have to acquire a global lock on all tables in the database. There's no way to know in advance what data your transaction will try to read or update, so a global lock is the only real guarantee.

Both Oracle and MySQL have a transaction isolation level that they term SERIALIZABLE, but they take an optimistic strategy. Though each does so in different ways, neither does a global lock as I described above.

MySQL implements SERIALIZABLE in a simple way: Every `SELECT` is implicitly `SELECT...LOCK IN SHARE MODE` (known as `SELECT...FOR SHARE` in 8.0). This means that if two sessions read the data and then try to update it as shown in the balance debit example in the paper, they'll cause a deadlock because both updates will be waiting for the other to release its shared read lock.

Oracle allows you to read and update data, and acquires locks optimistically (i.e. at the time you read or update). But if you try to update data that has been modified since your transaction began, you get this error:

```
ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
```

In both Oracle and MySQL, the best remedy for the ACIDRain vulnerability has nothing to do with isolation level. The remedy is to avoid the race condition by using [explicit locking reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) using the `FOR UPDATE` query option. That ensures exclusive access to the data starting at the time you read the data.

Another remedy would be to issue explicit table-locking commands, such as [LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) in MySQL or [LOCK TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9015.htm) in Oracle.

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html
- https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-transaction-isolation-levels

Comment: Does this also apply to postgresql?

Comment: I suggest you find the PostgreSQL documentation on how they implement SERIALIZABLE.

Comment: I think that answer is misleading. All you have to do is to write your application correctly, then it won't be vulnerable to these attacks. It is not necessary to actually serialize all database access. The hard part is of course to prove that the application is safe.

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL the case is simple: if you use the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, you are automatically safe from such attacks. This is because `SERIALIZABLE` in PostgreSQL guarantees “true” serializability: if all transactions involved run at that level, the result of the workload is equivalent to some serialized execution of the transactions. No anomalies are possible.

The price you are paying is twofold:

- `SERIALIZABLE` incurs an extra cost, because predicate locks have to be maintained.
- You have to be ready to repeat every transaction in case you receive a “serialization error”.

Of course, if an application doesn't use transactions at all, there is no way to make it safe...